# How tablelayout can equal with layout width?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I want to make application can show data from RecyclerView, but it's show different column sizes. How can I make tablelayout equal column size for the layout, because I have no idea with this?

This is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    >
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="9"

   >
    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:weightSum="9"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:background="@drawable/borderc">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/namabar"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"
            android:text="Nama Barang"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="15"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/borderc"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:id="@+id/jumlahbar"
            android:text="Jumlah"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/borderc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:id="@+id/hargabar"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/borderc"
android:text="Harga"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/kodebar"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"
            android:background="@drawable/borderc"
android:text="kode"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each TextView should have equal weight =1

each TextView should have layout width = 0dp

remove weight sum

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:weightSum="9"` from `TableLayout` and from`TableRow` first. Now add `android:stretchColumns="*"` inside `TableLayout`.